# How to run script menu after new terminal window exits

Tags: linux, terminal, script, sh

I have a script that asks the user for input for options.

When selecting the option I have it so it runs a new terminal and executes another script for the specified option.

I still want the menu script on the first terminal to ask for user input rather than exiting the script. Some feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

> The following was copied from a comment by the OP:

Here is an example:

#### `menue.sh`

```
#!/binbash
clear
echo
echo
echo
echo "1. Option Here"
echo
echo -n "Choice"
read choice
echo $choice
case $choice in
  1) /root/scriptexample/./examplenewterminal.sh
     ;;
esac
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### `examplenewterminal.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "/root/scriptexample/./example.sh"
bash
clear
echo
```

#### `example.sh`

```
#!bin/bash
clear
echo
echo
echo
echo
commands here, etc.
When you Control + C example.sh to stop commands executing, I want the xterm menu
to close and the script to continue to load the menue.sh in the original terminal.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand.  If you want to create a menu in a script, you're probably using something like `select opt in "${options[@]}", which you can then use in subsequent parts of the script in the same terminal - is that similar to what you're doing?  Please post some of your code.

Comment: #!/binbash
echo

Comment: here is an example

menue.sh 

#!/binbash
clear
echo
echo
echo
echo "1. Option Here"
echo 
echo -n "Choice"
read choice
echo $choice
case $choice in 
                          1) /root/scriptexample/./examplenewterminal.sh;;
esac

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

examplenewterminal.sh
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "/root/scriptexample/./example.sh"; bash
clear
echo

example.sh
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo
echo
echo
echo
commands here etc 

when you control + c example.sh to stop commands executing I want the xterm menue to close and the script to continue to load the menue.sh in the original terminal.

Comment: Comments should be used, sparingly, for limited, succinct dialog with respondents.  When you are asked to post code or otherwise provide information to clarify your question — information that should have been in the question in the first place — your first instinct should be to [edit] the question and put the requested information there.  As you can see, posting code in a comment doesn’t work very well.  I have edited your question to try to include the code that you posted in a comment.  Please check it and [edit] it to fix it if there are problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your comment shows `menue.sh` starting with `#!/binbash`. 
   This should be `#!/bin/bash`. 
   Or, if you aren’t using any `bash`-specific code, you can just use `#!/bin/sh`.
2. You seem to be calling your scripts (from within the other scripts) as
   `/root/scriptexample/./examplenewterminal.sh` and
   `/root/scriptexample/./example.sh`. 
   These should probably be just `/root/scriptexample/examplenewterminal.sh` and
   `/root/scriptexample/example.sh`; i.e., the `/./` is unnecessary
   (and, while I guess it’s harmless, it’s confusing clutter). 
   You don’t need to use `./` whenever you’re running a script;
   you need to use it when you’re running a program (script or compiled binary)
   ***in the current directory***. 
   See [Problems when trying to execute sh file from another sh file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196138/23408).
3. When `example.sh` terminates,
   `examplenewterminal.sh` should continue running. 
   It, apparently, starts another `bash` shell (which I don’t understand);
   after *that* terminates,
   `examplenewterminal.sh` clears the screen, echoes a blank line, and ends. 
   When `examplenewterminal.sh` terminates, `menue.sh` should continue running. 
   But then it ends. 
   (What is the `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^` supposed to be? 
   Just a separator?) 
   If you add more code to `menue.sh` after the `esac`,
   or put the existing code into a loop,
   it should continue to run after `examplenewterminal.sh` terminates.